# Seed restore from one wallet to another

Tags: wallet-recovery, e-wallet, mnemonic-seed

Researching about restore walletS using seeds, I have one question:

- I have 1 Jaxx wallet and the seed assigned to it.
- Then, let´s say that I find another wallet that I like more, that supports the same cryptocurrencies that I had in Jaxx and also the same seed protocol (BIP39)

**Can I restore my previous wallet (basically, the same cryptocurrencies, amounts, addresses...) in the new wallet, using the seed that Jaxx provided to me?**

Then, there is one more question that comes to my mind...If the answer for the first question is "Yes": **Can I use two wallets at the same time that use the same seed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided both wallets support BIP39, you should be able to restore a seed from one into another easily.

Using the seed simultaneously on two different wallets is not a problem, since address generation is deterministic.

Note that BIP39 simply defines the seed process. BIP44 defines multiple coin types, BIP32 defines accounts. At a minimum, any seed based wallet must support these three. Most wallets these days support BIP49, BIP84, and BIP141 for segwit compatible addresses of various types. However, not all wallets support these, and even the ones that do might require you to explicitly select the correct address type and path (such as electrum). Make sure that the second wallet you use supports all the features of the first one.

Comment: Hi Raghav, thanks so much for these details :)


Anyway, I have not seen full info from wallets about the "BIP" standards that they support, or a list about wallets with their BIP support. Is there some web that I can check this info?

Comment: I'm not aware of any site that lists the supported address types for each wallet. You will likely have to contact each wallet's developers and ask them if the information is not available publicly. Alternatively, you might be able to tell the wallet type you are using if your wallet shows you the derivation path. It should look like `m/Number/more numbers and slashes`. The first number after the `m` should tell you the BIP being followed (`m/44`, `m/49`, etc.)